# Html table new rows create within the column ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I am stuck in the position that when I add new rows to the column, it's inserted within the 1st column of the table, not to every column.

The summary of the application is, there is a supplier list I am getting from the database. Then in one view, I added a table with permanent headings Description, Qty and other columns created count of the suppliers that request included.

Then I created another partial view, which connected to another model, In the main view user clicks the "Add" button, new rows should be created for each of the columns that are already there.

But the issue is, the new rows are created within the 1st column Description.

Here is some output of the issue. Currently there is one supplier JKW Holdings. So the Description column is there, Qty column is there, and the supplier is column. But when I click the add button Qty and Supplier column goes right side of the table and new rows created within the Description column.

Here is my code for main view

```
@model Asp_PASMVC.Models.PurchasingTable

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PurchaseDetails";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.RequestId)

<br />
<table width="100%" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Description</th>

            <th>Qty</th>

            @foreach (var item in Model.SuppList) //new columns will be created with the supplier count that user added earlier
            {
                <th>@item</th>
            }

            <th> <button type="button" id="addAnotherItem" class="btn btn-success" href="#">Add</button></th>  @*calling to the partial view*@
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="IteMLi">
        

        @if (Model != null && Model.PurchasingItemList != null)
        {
            foreach (Asp_PASMVC.Models.PurchasingDetails Emp in Model.PurchasingItemList)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("_PurchaseEmployees", Emp);
            }
        }



    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#addAnotherItem").click(function () {
            $.get('/AppRequests/AddPurchaseItemDetails', { Id: $('#RequestId').val() }, function (template) {
                $("#IteMLi").append(template);
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is the action result

```
public ActionResult AddPurchaseItemDetails(int Id)
{
    PurchasingDetails newM = new PurchasingDetails();

    int RId = db.Purchase.Where(x => x.Req_Id == Id).First().Id;
    var Supp = db.PurchasingItems
                 .Where(r => r.Purchase_Id == RId).ToList()
                 .Select(x => x.Supp_Id).ToList();

    List<PurchasingDetailsSup> Te = new List<PurchasingDetailsSup>();

    foreach (int item in Supp)
    {
        Te.Add(new PurchasingDetailsSup { Supp_Id = item });
    }

    newM.PurchasingDetailsSup = Te;

    return PartialView("_PurchaseDetails", newM);
}
```

This is the partial view

```
@model Asp_PASMVC.Models.PurchasingDetails
@using Asp_PASMVC.Infrastructure

@{
    List<SelectListItem> Suppliers = Session["SupplierList"] as List<SelectListItem>;
    List<SelectListItem> ItmDescription = Session["Itm_DesList"] as List<SelectListItem>;

}

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("PurchasingItemList"))
{

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TempID)

    <tr>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item_Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "" } })</td>

        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Qty, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "" } })</td>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PurchasingDetailsSup.Count; i++)
        {
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PurchasingDetailsSup[i].Unit_Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "" } })</td>
        }

        <td><a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>

}
```

Here is the current output
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you show the  html that is being generated?

Comment: You are rendering the column headers based on `Model.SuppList` and the table body rows based on `Model.PurchasingDetailsSup`. Since they are different lists there is a high chance that your table structure is not rendering right. e.g. more or less headers than column. Also you are rendering a `form` element within the `tbody` tag which is not a good idea.
Also can you share the html code from the browser's view source option?

Comment: @Rahatur this is the Html code. I copied it to google doc --> https://docs.google.com/document/d/17KPeGq6TQoiwX5KTTglA39_dycXLWmAvC6V4zTYcrUQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @allan this is the generated Html code of the table https://docs.google.com/document/d/17KPeGq6TQoiwX5KTTglA39_dycXLWmAvC6V4zTYcrUQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You should share the html on this page where it's visible to make it easier for people to review your code. The partial view and the html you have shared do not match up at all. I would expect to see the opening <tr><td> tags present in this html, but that is not the case. The  other thing is you are using "PurchasingItemList", but no where is this property defined on the PurchasingDetails  view model. Also, in the AddPurchaseItemDetails action, you are creating a PurchasingDetails object, which you then set with PurchasingDetailsSup , which only sets Supp_Id .

Comment: In the partial view however you are binding to a lot more properties than you have initialised in the action such as TempID, Item_Description, Qty etc. This code is not fully complete, so it does not look like you have populated all the required properties. You should try and go back to basics and make sure you have the right binding in place.